# How to "un-impersonate" (un-delegate?) in Kerberos

Tags: asp.net, iis, kerberos

I have a web application using Kerberos to access an external resource useing ASP.NET 3.5 and IIS.

When a user connects with the application, Kerberos authentication auto-magically allows me to connect to external resources acting as the user using delegation.  This was not easy to do.  It is nice, but I've a problem.  Sometimes I need to connect to an external resource using an account with more rights than the user.  The service account which the app-pool is running under has the addition rights I need.  How can I remove the user's Kerberos identification and connect with Kerberos using the service account running the application pool?

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure why I am getting no responses at all.  I've never seen that before.  Please post questions, they may clarify the problem (to me too).

---

> Woring in Kerberos and need an overview of delegation?  Read the first part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103747/215752.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a class:

```
public class ProcessIdentityScope : IDisposable
{
    private System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonationContext;
    private bool _disposed;

    public ProcessIdentityScope()
    {
        _impersonationContext = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _impersonationContext.Undo();
            _impersonationContext.Dispose();
            _disposed = true;
        }
        else
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("ProcessIdentityScope");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And I use it like so:

```
using(ProcessIdentityScope identityScope = new ProcessIdentityScope())
{
    // Any code in here runs under the Process Identity.
}
```

This code is based on this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx

Comment: Dang @Ryan, this looks like exactly what I want it to do.  I should get a chance to test it tomorrow.

Comment: BTW, this solution is working great in production, thanks again @Ryan