# Proxy reauthentication

Tags: authentication, proxy

I have an application that authenticates and authorizes the users within application. The application then connects to the database using a service ID. because of this, all actions on the database are run as the application and not the end user. I now have a requirement to tie all database actions to the end user. Can anyone tell me at a high level a couple of ways to solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two high level approaches.  One is to use something like [Kerberos Delegation ([Kerberos, delegation and how to do this correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606699/kerberos-delegation-and-how-to-do-this-correctly)) to actually take the user's authentication and log into the database as a user.  The much more common approach is to store the end-user's ID in all created or updated rows and to trust the application to do this correctly.