Can I impersonate and delegate a Windows Identity constructed from User Principal Name?
I want to impersonate a Windows Identity, but I only have a Claims Principal to go on. Using this I can construct a Windows Identity using the WindowsIdentity Upn string constructor, but ImpersonationLevel gets set to Identity for said user.
Is there some way to have this user call a webapi that uses Windows authentication and have said webapi impersonate the authenticated user to a second Windows service?
I also tried casting the ClaimsPrincipal to a Windows principal but was unsuccessful.

You need to set up Kerberos Delegation to be able to do that. https://woshub.com/configuring-kerberos-authentication-on-iis-website/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606699/kerberos-delegation-and-how-to-do-this-correctly
